# Including PHP files in header.php

Tags: headers

I have multiple header files, which are 90% the same code. It would make editing them easier if common code could be contained and called from a separate file.

However, neither "include" nor "get_template_part" do not appear to work in header.php. How could this be managed?

Comment: Include should work fine. Can you show us what you're trying?

Comment: `get_template_part()` should also work fine in header.php, please share your code

Comment: Yep, apologies: one of those days where you try 90 things and the first thing actually worked without you noticing.